# Difference between returning false and calling parent's eventFilter to propagate the event

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a class inherited from `QDialog` that implements `eventFilter` to log some events. After logging the event I want to pass it *later*. What's the difference between `return false;` and `return QDialog::eventFilter(obj, event);` at this point? I've seen both options used in Qt examples.

Answer (score 0):

The [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) says, that

> ... unhandled events are passed to the base class's eventFilter() function, since the base class might have reimplemented eventFilter() for its own internal purposes.

i.e. if you handle an event in your event filter, you should either return true or false, the rest of events should be propagated to the parent class, because it might implement its own filter too.

Comment: Does it mean that `return false;` does **not** propagate the event to the parent class? What does "handled further" mean then?

Comment: No, if filter returns false, the event will be processed/handled as if there is no filter exist. It's an equivalent to propagating the event. Look at the example (see the link to Qt docs). It returns *true* for key press event and when you press a key - nothing happens.

Comment: I understand the `true` case, but don't understand what will change if we omit `else { return false; }` and move `return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);` from the top else clause to the function end

Comment: `return false` means, you handled the event yourself and didn't filter it. The rest of cases should be propogated.